Animated Cinderella-like short film on YouTube about a girl with a pet cow and an evil stepfamily
Can anyone help identify an animated short film on YouTube that’s similar to Cinderella?
This was a professionally animated short film about a girl whose biological parents were murdered when she was a baby. The parents sent her away with their pet cow, and the next scene shows them terrified, with a lot of crows (or some black creatures) on the roof.
The girl grows up on a farm with an evil stepmother and stepsisters, still with the cow. At some point, the cow helps her with something, but the stepmother kills it and serves it as a meal.
The film ends with a lonely tree on a hill, where a prince picks an apple. I also remember the sky being dark grey throughout the film.
I remember watching it on YouTube, probably around 2016–2017.

Can you think of any other details that might help? For example, was this a professionally done animation or something cheap and experimental? Were there any voice actors you recognised? Was this aimed at adults or kids? What were the character's names?

I'm at a loss why this would attract a close vote. It's incredibly clear what OP is after and anyone who recognises it would be able to instantly confirm that it's the correct property.

@Valorum hi! You might be talking about Cindrella, but unfortunately it’s not. Also yes, it was professionally animated. I don’t remember the rest.

@Valorum I'm confused. This question is about identifying a work, while identification questions are off-topic here. Can you please tell me what's going on here?

@EtackSxchange - Meat's back on the menu.

@EtackSxchange Support for ID questions has been re-affirmed by the community. They've been on-topic for a while now. See the [meta] post: What does the community want to do with identification questions? (note the top-voted answers).
